# iPhone missing from Screen Time on other devices

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, screen-time

My iPhone SE 2020 doesn't appear in Screen Time on my Mac or iPad.

All devices are signed into the same iCloud account and fully updated to the latest operating system releases.

All have 'Share Across Devices' enabled in Screen Time. The Mac and iPad appear in Screen Time on all three devices but the iPhone's data only shows up on the iPhone itself.

Tried:

- Toggling 'Share Across Devices', on iPhone
- Toggling 'Share Across Devices', on all three devices at the same time
- Toggling Screen Time on iPhone
- Toggling Screen Time on all 3 devices (with all off at the same time)
- Logging out of iCloud and logging back in on iPhone

Comment: I have the same problem.  I tried everything you did and couldn't get it to work correctly.  I gave up and hope Apple fixes it (someday).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Richard, but I don’t think Apple has patched the glitch. You can try updating iOS to the latest on all of your devices.